# Adding Fields for Rollup Summary- Default 5

Tags: roll-up-summary

[image]

I need more than the five available. Where can I define the usage amount? Usage is set to 5. Limit is set to 25.

[image]

Comment: Usage means the total number of roll up summaries you have already created (5 out of the maximum 25). This is different from the number of field filter criteria you can have per roll up summary, which is also five. You can't change the number of filter criteria, but you can generally work around this restriction.

Comment: What edition are you using? Developer, Essentials, Professional, Enterprise, Unlimited? It's also not very clear what you're asking about (are you talking about the 5 criteria per rollup summary, or can you not create any more than 5 rollup summary fields despite the displayed limit being 25?)

Comment: Pardon the confusion. I am Concerned with the filter Criteria. 
What I need is to add more conditional product family categories. Those currently being the Radio, IC, FCC, etc, If I cant change the number of filter criteria, should I move to working out a formula? The Edition it enterprise I believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot add more filter criteria than five to a Roll-Up Summary Field, and you cannot filter a Roll-Up Summary Field by a formula field.

Your two primary options are:

1. Use an Apex trigger or declarative automation to evaluate more complex criteria and populate a new, non-formula field on the object with the results. Then, filter your Roll-Up Summary Field by that new field.
2. Use a 3rd party product like [Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries) instead of a native RUSF. (This is a much bigger change and should be considered carefully).

Comment: I appreciate the knowledge David. Going to look into using Apex. Cheers!